# Reactive Form Validators.Required not functioning on formControls

Tags: angular5, angular-reactive-forms

Here is the mock data array i am looping over in my app.component.html

```
questions: [
{question: 'Question-1'},
{question: 'Question-2'},
{{question: 'Question-3'}
]
```

In my app.component.ts as follows, Since i am using reactive form approach i have instantiated the Form Group and declare a formControl named 'note' which is declared as required:

export class example {

```
regPresentationForm: FormGroup;

this.regPresentationForm = new FormGroup ({
   note: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
});
```

}

In my component HTML i am looping over the array and displaying the text field, therefore will have three text boxes each with **note as my formControl**:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor = "let question of questions">
  <textarea type="text" id="textArea" placeholder="Enter the Note" class="form-control" formControlName = "note">
  </textarea>
</ng-container>
```

Since the note formcontrol is required i am disabling the submit button like this:

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"[disabled] =  "!regPresentationForm.valid">
  Save & Continue
</button>
```

**PROBLEM:**

The problem is the form get valid if i enter a text on the first text box therefore angular is considering it as a single box repeated thrice, which should not happen it should consider each note field seperately (3 instance of note formcontrol since the iteration is done thrice)

No idea how to figure this out need helps.

I hope i am clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop formControl like this : 
 On ts side:

```
 form2: FormGroup;
 testData:any;
 formDataInfo: any;


  constructor() {  }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.testData = [];
    this.formDataInfo = {}; 

   for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
    var currentNote = 'note' + i;

    this.formDataInfo[currentNote] = new FormControl(null, 
    Validators.required);

    this.testData.push({ "value": currentNote, "key": "firstName1", 
      "label": "First name",
      "required": true, "order": 1, "controlType": "textbox", 
      "type": "text" 
    }); 

  }
  this.form2 = new FormGroup (
    this.formDataInfo
  );
}
```

On HTML side:

```
<div [formGroup]="form2">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let question of testData" class="form-row">
    {{question | json}} {{question.key}}
        <textarea type="text" placeholder="Enter the Note"    
          class="form-control" [formControlName]="question.value" 
          [required]="question.required"> 
        </textarea> 
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to loop form control using questions on ts side

Comment: Exactly on the ts side i need to loop too.. As you answered on the ts side you are adding manually the note formControls which i need to do it dynamically depending on the array.. I will loop on the questions array at the ts side too in order to have as many form controls as per iteration

Comment: Yes. That's only possible solution i guess

Comment: But the problem is i am trying and on the ts side i am not able to add the formControl key dynamically as you suggested on the html using note{{$index}. I am trying on the ts side this way: `notes${this.i}` where i is the loop iterator index. But the formGroup key can't take this expression. Still no idea how to achieve the solution.

Comment: I edited my answer. you can follow this one. let me know if you still have error.

Comment: But i can't see how you loop on the ts side to dynamically add the key to the form controls instead of writing manually, the point is the array has no fixed number of elements it could change..hence i need to loop at the ts side to dynamically insert into the formGroup instance the formControlName dynamically

Comment: I modified answer with a loop. you can replace own loop with i variable.

Comment: Thats seem to me a great solution..gonna try it! Thank you by the way!

Comment: For this use case as mine what do you suggest dipten for the Tempate driven form?

Comment: Yeah. Template driven is best one in this case. And please upvote my answer if you find useful. Thanks

Comment: Since my reputation is less than 15 i can't upvote but if this solution works i will mark it correct..

Comment: I have tried your solution it gives an error since we are not passing a formGroup instance for example:   this.form2 = new FormGroup ({
    name: new FormControl(null,required)
  });

Comment: We are adding form control as in object formdatainfo and that objet we are passing in formgroup

Comment: Add this import line at the top of file: import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';